# How do I format date when using typeORM Select Query Builder?

Tags: javascript, typeorm

I'm using `@CreateDateColumn()` in model. When Select using Query Builder, how do I format the date in select content?

```
  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;
```

```
    const documentarys = await getManager()
      .getRepository(IncomingDocumentary)
      .createQueryBuilder('d')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('d.tireBrand', 't')
      .select([
        'd.code as code',
        'd.tireSize as tireSize',
        'd.applicableCarModel as applicableCarModel',
        'd.amount as amount',
        'd.price as price',
        'd.createdAt as createTime',
        't.name as tireBrandName',
      ])
      .getRawMany();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have an easier time to format it after selecting it with JavaScript, but if you really want to format it in the select query, you should use your database features. For example, if you have an SQL based database, you can format it like this:

```
const documentarys = await getManager()
  .getRepository(IncomingDocumentary)
  .createQueryBuilder('d')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('d.tireBrand', 't')
  .select([
    'd.code AS code',
    'd."tireSize" AS "tireSize"',
    'd."applicableCarModel" AS "applicableCarModel"',
    'd.amount AS amount',
    'd.price AS price',
    'TO_CHAR(d."createdAt"::DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS "createTime"',
    't.name AS "tireBrandName"',
  ])
  .getRawMany();
```

Comment: 'TO_CHAR(d.createdAt::DATE, "dd/mm/yyyy") as createTime',

and get an error:

QueryFailedError: column d.createdat does not exist

how to reslove it?

Comment: In case others have the same issue: You need to wrap camelCase column names in double quotes `d."createdAt"`. You're likely using a db like postgres. See link for more details: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1600670#:~:text=PostgreSQL%20converts%20all%20table%20column,uppercase%20letters%20cannot%20be%20queried.

Comment: Don't forget to use `""` if your aliases or column names are case sensitive.